# WPF reutilizar vista desde distintos modulos

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Cual es la manera mas óptima de reutilizar una vista.xaml, que pertenezca a otra librería de clases (otro modulo) en WPF utilizando MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a usar diferentes Views con el mismo ViewModel, no te lo recomiendo en absoluto. Yo al empezar con WPF lo intenté y luego ha sido un desastre para mantenerlo. Lo ideal es que cada view lleve asociado un ViewModel independiente.

Por el contrario, si lo que quieres es hacer componentes reutilizables, sí que puedes crear una librería de controles de usuario (UserControl), cada uno con su XAML y su CodeBehind, que podrás usarlos en todos los proyectos que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas simple es creando un proyecto del tipo `WPF User Control Library` alli defines esa vista como control.

Luego agreas la referencia al proyecto, para poder definir el namespace en el xaml quede quieres definir la vista, algo como ser

```
xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:NombreControlLibrary;assembly=NombreControlLibrary"
```

Observaras que al ser un proyecto separado debes definir el nombre del `assembly`

[How to: Import a Namespace into XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb514546(v=vs.90).aspx)

**Nota:** si en el link cambias el `en-US` por `es-ES` podras ver el articulo en español

Comment: Leandro buenas tardes, yo no hago referencia como tu mencionas, lo que yo hago es utilizar RegionManager para llamar a las vistas, y en efecto si funciona, pero un poco tedioso es tener que estar gestionando dichas Regiones durante el tiempo de ejecucion, tu has usado RegionManager para estas tareas de llamar a otras vistas de diferentes modulos?